# How can I add unknow Table as source for XtraReport

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xtrareport

I'm sorry for not being able to explain this but now I'll elaborate what I want to do. I'm working on a .NET software(Windows Form, C#) with SQL Server, I'm using devexpress xtrareport(First time actually) for report printing and here comes my porblem, I have a table (let's call it invoice table) and it contains a column for products which contains table name for the products table of that invoice, each time the product table is new and I don't know how can I print that product table? How can I even add it as a datasource when It's not created yet.

Comment: Start over. Your problem is self-induced by improper database design. Worse, anything can obviously be stored in this invoice table - your strings could contain nonsense. You will need complicated dynamic sql to retrieve the content of these columns and then fabricate more tsql to create a dynamic statement to retrieve the actual values you desire. There are lots of sample databases to review to see how invoices and products are usually related - including the [MS ones](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases).

Comment: Ok, I'll change but please answer me this, how am I supposed to bind the data to the design when the table isn't created yet. Of course if I go with any approach, there would be scenario like this.. How am I supposed to deal with that? And secondly how can I display variable values to the print.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use the stock SqlDataSource, instead you should use the [ObjectDataSource](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119313/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/provide-data-to-reports/bind-a-report-to-a-data-source/object-data-source) so you will manually fill the DTO and pass it to report